# MPI cannot execute with machine file or hosts from SSH using JSch exec channel

Tags: ssh, mpi, exec, jsch

OpenMPI runs fine on any MPI program executed by shell (using PuTTy or JSch) but if you use "exec" channel of JSch or terminal in WinSCP and specify any slave (compute node) it fails and exits with code 133 and following error message is displayed:

> mpirun -H compute-0-18 ranker.o

---

mpirun was unable to launch the specified application as it could not find an executable:

Executable: ranker.o
Node: compute-0-18

while attempting to start process rank 0.

---

It runs fine when the "-H compute-0-18" used to define host/slave machines/nodes is removed. It happens across two separate versions of OpenMPI 1.6.2 & 1.8.4.

This command runs fine in PuTTy and JSch "shell" channel.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how you start your job and in which environment?

Comment: Does it really output only that *single* line? Can you enable a more verbose logging?

Comment: Edited the question to include relevant information.